# How to make page template with admin able to select NextGen Galleries to be part of the layout?

Tags: page-template, plugin-nextgen-gallery

I'm trying to make a product page template, editable by client, which will have 3 different  NextGen Galleries per page.

In the product page admin area, I want the client to be able to select which 3 NextGen galleries to display, and in which order.

What do I put in my template page, and (I'm assuming) functions.php?

Here's a mockup of an individual product page how I want it to be, so you can see what I mean:
https://dl.dropbox.com/u/10452828/LRG/a-project-page-mockup.jpg

I'm customising a theme, in which all the 'About the Product' fields etc are in the page template already, I just want to add selectable NextGen Galleries.

I've tried googling this but I'm not sure of exactly what terminology I should be searching for, so any advice would be appreciated. Thankyou!

Comment: Just to clarify, I want it to be an actual part of the page template itself, with an input box for each gallery number (or similar controlled interface), not just shortcodes they would use in the content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add galleries directly to a template by calling [do_shortcode()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_shortcode) to run the gallery shortcode.

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[nggallery id="1" template="example"]'); ?>
```

Edit: sorry, writing decaffeinated so short attention span :)

Add some custom fields to your product pages to let your client pick which gallery goes on that product. If you like, just use the [Advanced Custom Fields](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/) plugin and its friend the [NextGEN Gallery Field add-on](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/advanced-custom-fields-nextgen-gallery-field-add-on/), which will let you add drop-down lists of gallery names to your edit pages.

Then in the template, get the value of each custom field and load the gallery using the shortcode as above, like this (replace 'gallery1' with your custom field names):

```
<?php
$gallery = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'gallery1', true);
if ($gallery) {
    echo do_shortcode("[nggallery id='$gallery' template='example']");
}
?>
```

Comment: Yes, thankyou. 
But how do I create the product page template so that it runs the client selected galleries for that particular product?

Comment: @Aaron: please see updated answer

Comment: You, sir, are a hero. I shall try that and report back. Many thanks!

Comment: NB: if you're going to use the Advanced Custom Field plugin and the NextGEN add-on, look at their code samples as their custom fields return more than just the gallery ID.

Comment: I'm finally getting the chance to try this tonight - just wanted you to know I hadn't abandoned this thread! Really appreciate the answer.

Comment: Ahhhh dammit, NextGen doesn't want to display a gallery by that name ID at all, only by its official NextGen ID number.
 
But I don't know how to get that number when the plugin only gives me that custom field name. Hmmm. Any ideas?

Thankyou very much for your advice so far...

Comment: Did you look at the sample code on the [ACF NextGEN Gallery addon plugin page](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/advanced-custom-fields-nextgen-gallery-field-add-on/)?

Comment: I did, but I had overlooked something! Had to get someone to explain the php to me, and make a couple of adjustments, but I got there in the end. 
Thankyou for your advice, that was really helpful :)